# Bad Request Error on POST request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I am trying to do a POST request and I am getting a "Bad Request" error. If anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong here, I would be grateful.

```
function mkSentiTopics() {
    dta['n_clusters'] = 3;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://saxonydemoubuntu.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/sentitopic",
        data: JSON.stringify(dta),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
            alert("success");
        },
        beforeSend: function() {

        },
        error: function(xhr, stats) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

"dta" is a dictionary

```
// dta["sentis"] is a list of numbers
// dta["texts"] is a list of strings
// dta["n_clusters"] is an int.
```

Comment: No idea, but whatever you're sending is not something the API will accept, hence the error. It's the server telling you your request is malformed. Check the API documentation. That said, terminology like _list_ and _dictionary_ which is common from in languages are called Object and Array in JavaScript. Similarly, it has no `int`. This may actually be where the problem lies: once you `JSON.stringify(dta)`, check that the types you are passing are correct (JSON only knows about boolean, array, object, string and number, note that `true !== "true"`, `1 !== "1"` and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the structure of the payload you are sending to the server does not match what it expects, so it rejects it. Not knowing the API signature, we can't help with that.

However, I'm going to take a shot in the dark and make the following suggestion based on this part of your post:

```
// dta["sentis"] is a list of numbers
// dta["texts"] is a list of strings
// dta["n_clusters"] is an int.
```

When you `JSON.stringify(dta)`, ensure that the output *exactly matches* what the API expects, noting that JSON only knows about boolean, array, object, string and number, further noting that `true !== "true"`, `1 !== "1"` and so on.

Example:

```js
let dta = {                 // Note object wrapper
  sentis: [1, 2, 3, 4],     // Note lack of ""
  texts: ["a", "b", "c"],   // Note presence of ""
  n_clusters: 5             // 'Naked' number
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dta, 0, 1)); // Note that "dta" is not a root key
```

If your API requires that the root key "dta" is present, or that the structure is different, modify your `dta` object accordingly.